# Node.js express: confuse about ejs template

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I put my `ejs` template file in `views` folder like:

```
views
|
|--foo.html
|
|--layout.html
```

so I config my ejs template:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

I render my `foo` template by this:

```
res.render('foo.html', {title: 'test'});
```

I want use `layout.html` as the master layout template, I also add `<%- body%>` tag in `layout.html`, but is doesn't work, what I saw is only return the ended `foo.html`.

Why the `layout.html` can't be the master layout?Or how can I set it to the master layout?

Comment: If you want/can you can stay on Express 2.x and use EJS while the official docs are updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahah you just got tricked by Express 3 change in layout management.
The official example: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/ejs
Has not been updated.

In Jade you now have to use blocks and extend the layout.
http://www.devthought.com/code/use-jade-blocks-not-layouts/

Comment: Thank for the url  "examples/ejs". It really helped me a lot understanding templates using ejs, express and Node.js

Answer (score 2):

Try to use ejs-locals then you can do this in a login.ejs file:

```
<% layout('layout') -%>
<form></form>
```