# Ejs engine with html not working

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

i'm using html files instead of ejs, but the express engine is ejs

```
views
|
|--header.html
|--footer.html
|
|--index.html
```

I configured like

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

I render my `index` template by this:

```
res.render('index.html', {title: 'test'});
```

But how can i include header and footer.html in  index.html

Similar posts
[Node.js express: confuse about ejs template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000824/node-js-express-confuse-about-ejs-template)

Existing example which is not working
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/ejs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original method for what you asked would be to use partials. Partials have since been removed, and replaced with the `include` function of EJS. This is how you would include a file:

```
<% include header.html %>
<% include footer.html %>
```

Any locals you pass to the rendered page will also be passed to an include. For example:

**app.js**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render(__dirname + '/index.html', {
    string: 'random_value',
    other: 'value'
  });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <%= other %>
  <% include content.html %>
</body>
```

**content.html**

```
<pre><%= string %></pre>
```

The resultant HTML you would get is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  value
  <pre>random_value</pre>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried same it's not working. 
How the app configure should be?
Hers is my code [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dwx3ypr51h3iar2/ejs_html.zip)

Comment: Is it working for you, i'm getting error like  `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.Function (<anonymous>)
    at exports.compile (C:\workspace\ejs_html\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:209:12)
    at Object.exports.render (C:\workspace\ejs_html\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:245:10)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\workspace\ejs_html\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:275:22)
    at View.render (C:\workspace\ejs_html\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render`

Comment: Try reinstalling or updating your modules.

Comment: My bad, i updated to ejs 0.8.4 version and its working fine.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there a way to make it so you don't have to include `__dirname`?

Comment: I don't have a development environment open to check, but you could try `./index.html` or `index.html`.

Comment: I had the same problem, after running command "npm update ejs --save" the include is working fine.

Comment: Wow, man, thanks, long after the fact, I was looking at why do the partials and looking for ejs files not work, then I cam accross this. Thanks, good stuff.