# Undefined error despite linking HTML correctly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have linked the routes to the html but the html keep showing agentData is not defined. Why is it giving me this error
despite linking it correctly. The app.js code is where I link the routes for login and admin. Routes is where the login
control where user go based on username and password. I render the html page once they login in routes.js and then in
admin.js, is where it gets all the data from mysql database and output as table. As you can see, I did declare agentData
in admin.js. However, if I remove the app.get/admin in routes.js, they gv me another error cannot /Get admin error. What
should I do?

routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../server');

router.get("/",  async function (request, response) {
    response.render("login.ejs");
  });

  router.get("/register", async function (req, res) {
    res.render("register.ejs");
  });

  router.post("/login", async function (request, response) {
    const { username, password } = request.body;

    if (username == 2 && password == 2) {
      response.redirect("/admin");
    } 

    else {
      return response.status(401).json({
        message: "Auth fail",
      });
    }
  });

  router.get('/admin', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('reach page');
    const sql='SELECT * FROM agentavia';
    db.query(sql, function (err, data, fields) {
      console.log(data);
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render('adminhome', { title: 'Agent List', agentData: data});
  });
  });
  
  router.get('/edit/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    const AgentId= req.params.id;
    const sql=`SELECT * FROM agentavia WHERE id=${AgentId}`;
    db.query(sql, function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.render('modifyAgent', { title: 'Agent List', editData: data[0]});
    });
  });
  
  router.post('/edit/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    const id= req.params.id;
      const updateData=req.body;
      const sql = `UPDATE agentavia SET ? WHERE id= ?`;
      db.query(sql, [updateData, id], function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(data.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
    });
    res.redirect('/admin');
  });
  
  module.exports = router;
```

adminhome.ejs

```
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>S.N</th>
            <th>Agent Name</th>
            <th>Agent ID</th>
            <th>AgentStatus</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>

        <% if(agentData.length!=0){ var i=1; agentData.forEach(function(data){ %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=i; %></td>
            <td><%=data.agentName %></td>
            <td><%=data.agentID %></td>
            <td><%=data.agentStatus %></td>
            <td><a href="/admin/edit/<%=data.id%>">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <% i++; }) %> <% } else{ %>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">No Data Found</td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
```

modifyagent.ejs

```
<div class="agent-detail">
   
    <form action="<%=(typeof editData!='undefined')?'/admin/edit/'+editData.id:'/admin/create'%>" method="POST">
          <label>Agent Name</label>
          <input type="agentname" placeholder="Enter Agent Name" name="agentName" required value="<%=(typeof editData!='undefined')? editData.agentName:''%>">
          <label>Agent ID</label>
          <input type="agentID" placeholder="Enter Agent ID" name="agentID" required value="<%=(typeof editData!='undefined')? editData.agentID:''%>">
          <label>Agent Status</label>
          <input type="Agent Status" placeholder="Enter Agent Status" name="agentStatus" required value="<%=(typeof editData!='undefined')? editData.agentStatus:''%>">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you check is this records are in the table SELECT * FROM agentavia?

Comment: You should not have a `app.get(...` inside another `app.get(...` in your `routes.js` file. That's not how it works, it would mean that someone already logged in would not be able to access `/admin` if you restart your server. Also, why have it there, since you have it correctly defined in `admin.js`? You cannot have it defined in multiple places. And as suggested by @VijayPalaskar, try to `console.log(data)` right above `res.render('adminhome', { title...` to see whether that data is there

Comment: yes, i did have the records inside. I manage to even make it work in another folder so I am transferring it bit by bit into the original project folder I make which I showing here. As for the app.get part, actually there is an existing sample when I saw from other sample and it works perfectly fine. So is it a better practise to use router instead of app.get?

Comment: yes router instead of app.get. I think issue in yur file extension.can you check wether it will work with ..ejs extension?

Comment: I have tried placing console.log before rendering the page. It didn't manage to give any data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Issue in your file extension. it should be **adminhome.ejs** instead of
adminhome.html

Or Another way is to using includes

For How to use with includes Refer this [Ejs engine with html not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753620/ejs-engine-with-html-not-working?rq=1)

this example I have tested on local.It's working fine

app.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();

    // set the view engine to ejs
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    // index page 
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        var data = [
            { id: 1,agentName: 'Bloody Mary', agentID: 3,agentStatus: 'yes' },
            { id:2,agentName: 'Martini', agentID: 5 ,agentStatus: 'no'},
            { id:3,agentName: 'Scotch', agentID: 10 ,agentStatus: 'yes'}
        ];


        res.render('index', {
            agentData: data
        });
    });

    app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at 3000'));
```

Index.ejs

```
    <h2>Loop</h2>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>S.N</th>
          <th>Agent Name</th>
          <th>Agent ID</th>
          <th>AgentStatus</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
      
        <% if(agentData.length!=0){ var i=1; agentData.forEach(function(data){ %>
        <tr>
          <td><%=i; %></td>
          <td><%=data.agentName %></td>
          <td><%=data.agentID %></td>
          <td><%=data.agentStatus %></td>
          <td><a href="/agents/edit/<%=data.id%>">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <% i++; }) %> <% } else{ %>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="7">No Data Found</td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
      </table>
```

Ejs reference:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs

Comment: thank you for helping but I still received the same error agentData is not defined despite changing all the app.get to router.get. I have also change the adminhome.html to adminhome.ejs. Should I update the question with latest code?

Comment: to render the loops you need array .you are passing single object. means passing data[0] which is object. for this no need of loop. print  with <%=agentdata.agentName %>. hope this will solve your issue. I updated my answer check now

Comment: The loop is to render the entire list of data from mysql into the table.

Comment: see I have updated my answer.which I tested on my local server.it's working fine

Comment: sorry, maybe I modifed my qns again. Is it because of my login? Now I get another error assignment to constant variable.

Comment: what errosr giving now? can you display errors here?

Comment: Sorry please ignore the previous comment. Thank you very much Vijay! Sorry, one last question. How do I improve routing after login? The system dnt let me edit my comment just now...

Comment: you can redirect to login if authentication  fails  with passing error message & if success then redirect to dashboard page. I recommendeds to you  don't use ejs .use any frond end technology react,angular,vue js

Comment: Sorry, can you help me see my edit portion? It cannot get id even though the link and naming is correct?

Comment: Its in the routes.js below router.get("/admin") in the code above. The req.params.id is suppose to be based on the row number pressed but it is showing not get /admin/edit/1

Comment: Cannot GET /admin/edit/1  this message showing or another message showing?

Comment: Just cannot GET /admin/edit/1. I try clicking the others and have same result. I attached the form for that page. Although I doubt it is form issue though...

Comment: this messege showing because you have not defined any route. it will work with /edit/1
to /admin/edit/1 has to be work you need to define route like this   or app.use('/admin',load path of route file) ..all url of this route js file starts from /admin path.  Another way is to  router.get('admin/edit/:id',() => {})   but this is not better way.
it will  work
  refer this for more:  https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html