# How can I set different view engines for express app?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

My app needs multiple view engines Currently it is like this:

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

This works for html template but not for ejs templates.
(I saw similar question and tried to add consolidate module and followed instruction from their documentation but it is throwing errors )

Comment: You can try to set swig as the template engine after using conssolidate then you will be able to use multiple template engines.

Comment: Thanks all. figured it out. here is the link for others.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000824/node-js-express-confuse-about-ejs-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with express, `res.render` only receive one template engine, if you want to use multi template engine, you must make custom `render` function. Every template engine has `render` function to make view

Comment: Thanks I need more information. Link to documentation for custom render.

Comment: in ejs document : http://ejs.co/ , you will find render function, every template engine have same function. Use this function to render html from view then use res.send to response to user (logic behind res.render)